# get html of div and append same content to div but with only first element

Tags: jquery

I am not having much more hands on jquery.
i want to take a content of div and append same content to div but it adding multiple items.

May be this code explain my question clearly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var data = $('#xyz').html();
        $(data).appendTo("#xyz");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="xyz"><p>Test</p></span>
<button>ADD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am taking content of selector xyz and adding content to same selector which is working but its adding double time.

Current output

Test

**Add**

after clicking Add output will be

Test

Test

**Add**

Again after clicking Add output will be

Test

Test

Test

Test

**Add**

but i want it to be

Test

Test

Test

**Add**

not 4 Test only 3 Test

can any one help me to sort out this.

Comment: Based on your structure, this is the correct behaviour. See my answer below.

Comment: `var data = $('#xyz').html(); $("button").click(function(){          
  $("#xyz").append(data);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to capture the content of the span before the event handler:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $('#xyz').html();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(data).appendTo("#xyz");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="xyz"><p>Test</p></span>
<button>ADD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise it'll get the content when you click, which includes the content added by the previous click

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is the correct behaviour because every time you call `.html()` you are getting the entire contents of `#xyz` which is constantly changing. Example:

First load, `.html()` will return:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

First ADD, `.html()` will return:

```
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

Second ADD , `.html()` will return:

```
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

You are appending `x` new elements every time you press ADD. If you wanted to only add one line of `<span>` every time, [check this out](http://jsbin.com/qefonacoje/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var data = $('#xyz p')[0].outerHTML;
        $(data).appendTo("#xyz");
    });
});
```